# Is using rvalue reference to erased element of STL container undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, const-reference

Part of my program does something like this:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> G{{"1", 10}};

int m(const std::string& i, std::unordered_set<std::string>& v) {
    v.erase(i);
    return G.at(i);
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::string> v {"1"};
    const std::string& remove_this = *v.begin();
    return m(remove_this, v);
}
```

The program should be portable between linux and windows. When compiled with g++, the program runs well and returns 10, as expected. However, when compiled with VS 2017, the programs aborts, throwing an std::out_of_range. With most trivial effort of debugging, I see that `i` in function `m` is destroyed before the call to `G.at`. (both without optimizations)

To my understanding, the const reference to `v.begin()` should expire until `m` returns (the g++ case). But it MSVC obviously didn't agree with that.

Is this undefined behavior or implementation defined? When, indeed, does an argument passed by const reference expire then?

Comment: It is undefined behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, but that's about iterator, instead of values, isn't it?

Comment: *unordered_[multi]{set,map}: only iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated [23.2.5/13]*

Comment: @NathanOliver, ah..., thanks.

Comment: @YiFei: No values here, only references

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, sure, I meant the value the iterator pointed to. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The value that you just deleted? Gee, I wonder why reading it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `i` lives until `m` ends. However, the object that `i` references disappears after `v.erase(i)`, leaving `i` as a dangling reference. `G.at(i)` then reads from the dangling reference causing undefined behavior.